# Waiting for API to finish in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

In Angular, does anybody know of an easy way I can get my component to wait a few seconds to make sure the call to the `moratoriumService.PostMoratoriumLocationsArray()` method finishes up before the `navigateByUrl()` kicks in on the router. Code is below. Any suggestions would be most appreciated. --Jason

```
 PostMoratoriumLocationsArray(moraID: any, moratoriumLocationsarray: MoratoriumLocation[]): Observable<any> {
    this.moratoriumService.PostMoratoriumLocationsArray(moraID, moratoriumLocationsarray)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe((data) => (this.moratoriumID) = (data),
        (error) => (console.log(error)),
        () => console.log('Post moratorium location for moratorium is complete'),
      );
    this.router.navigateByUrl('ActiveMoratoriums');
    return of(this.moratoriumID);
  }
```

Comment: Moving the navigateByUrl statement to the complete handler of the observable should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is async function you may not know how long server response. You should
try below code

```
PostMoratoriumLocationsArray(moraID: any, moratoriumLocationsarray: MoratoriumLocation[]): Observable<any> {
    var subject = new Subject<string>();
    this.moratoriumService.PostMoratoriumLocationsArray(moraID, moratoriumLocationsarray)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe((data) => {
          (this.moratoriumID) = (data);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('ActiveMoratoriums');
           subject.next(data);
        },
        (error) => (console.log(error)),
        () => console.log('Post moratorium location for moratorium is complete'),
      );
      return subject.asObservable();
  }
```

Comment: Instead you could just add `tap` in the pipe and skip the subscribe

Comment: @pc_coder -Thank you that appears to have worked. Still new to Angular . So in this case it appears the Subject more or less consumes the data ? --Jason

Answer (score 0):

How about building on the observable inside the pipe instead, and let the caller subscribe? Like this.

```
PostMoratoriumLocationsArray(moraID: any, moratoriumLocationsarray: MoratoriumLocation[]): Observable<any> {
    return this.moratoriumService.PostMoratoriumLocationsArray(moraID, moratoriumLocationsarray)
               .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
                     tap(data => 
                         {
                             this.moratoriumID = data
                             this.router.navigateByUrl('ActiveMoratoriums');
                         },
                         error => console.log(error),
                         () => console.log('Post moratorium location for moratorium is complete'),
      ));
  }
```

And when you call the method, you do this: `this.PostMoratoriumLocationsArray(...).subscribe()`